# Cannot access vue-cookies in typescript

Tags: typescript, components, vuejs3

I've added vue-cookies to my app *main.ts*:

```
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';
...
const app = createApp(App)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(router)
  .use(VueCookies,{ 
  expires: '30d', 
});
```

When I want to access the cookie variable, it cannot find it. I've tried all sorts of things:

```
export default defineComponent({
...
 methods:{
  likePokemon(name: string){
    window.$cookies.set("username", "test");
    this.$cookies.get("username"));
    Vue.cookie.get('access_token');
  },
 ...
 }
}
```

I get the error *Property '$cookies' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}*

Answer (score 0):

It seems 'vue-cookies' doesn't support Vue3. Instead use https://github.com/anish2690/vue-cookie-next